# how to make unchangeable console in c?

Tags: c, console, size

I'm making a small project using only words but if user modify the size of console, the line of words are messed. I found how to set the size of console. However, There is no way to fix the size of console What can I do? plz help me.

Comment: To begin with, please take some time to ead [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), take the SO [tour], read [ask], as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). Also please learn how to create a [mre] and how to [edit] your questions.

Comment: As for your problem, it's *very* dependent on operating system and the "console" you're using. None of which you tell us about.

Comment: Never alter the console for the user. That is very rude. You need to adjust your program to their settings.